# Snapshot not loading data in physical device but loading in the virtual device in Android studio

Tags: android, flutter, api, snapshot

Using open weather api the snapshot is loading correctly in the virtual device (edge browser) but not loading in the physical device.

I have tried correcting the key that open weather provides, i have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app
[Here i have connected my physical device for output, and the URL is the one that is need to be loaded and the json data has to be stored in the snapshot, its all working correctly when i run this app on the edge web browser but its not running on the physical device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAIR1.jpg)